# How to fix pygame installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making an online tetris game that requires a pygame installation on my laptop. For some reason, it won't let me run even though I successfully imported it.

I ran the following command:

```
py -3.7 -m pip install pygame
```

which gave me the following line:

> Installing collected packages: pygame Successfully installed
> pygame-1.9.6

I then wrote import pygame in the first line of my code:

`import pygame`

and the error I got was:

> Unable to import 'pygame'pylint(import-error)

What would be the fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading the library:

pip install --upgrade pygame